# Looking for a convertible laptop with some requirements that aren't that typical of a convertible

Tags: laptop, development

I'm looking for a laptop. I plan on using it for watching videos and possibly some graphical design. This is why I'd like it to be a convertible. It's pretty inconvenient to do those things with a big keyboard in your way. Also, I need a minimum resolution of 1080p ( I wouldn't mind having higher but I don't have much to gain by going higher than that ). Lastly I'd like hardware compatible with hackintosh. I want to use hackintosh for development. I plan on using Xcode to compile any apps I make to ios and I'd like to be able to test programs I write on mac. Also I will probably end up writing code on this laptop. With these things in mind there's a good chance I will be doing a fair amount of compiling. Thats why I would like it like it to be quad-core.

Here are some features that I would like, but aren't totally necessary:

- no number pad ( it effects the shape of the keyboard and I think it looks ugly ),
- touchscreen ( I'd use that for drawing ),
- An SSD would be nice for fast boot,
- not to flimsy ( a lot of laptops now are really thin and lightweight. I don't want something too different from that but I'd prefer something that doesn't feel flimsy. This isn't that necessary though. I'll take whatever I can get with all these requirements I've listed ;) )

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will be easy to find such a laptop, because "convertible" usually implies "Intel U" processor (which are all dual-cores) and not one of those 45W quad-core-processors...